# MySql Query string date issue

Tags: mysql, date, syntax, query-string

I have this query string here ($month = 11):

```
select * from members where CURDATE() = DATE_ADD(renewal_date, INTERVAL $month MONTH);
```

What this query string will do is get all my members with a renewal_date from 11 months ago from the current date

I also have two other fields, reminder_date and blocker. What I am looking to add is, to get members with a reminder_date from 1 month ago from the current date and if the blocker is not equal to 1 (blocker can be 0 or 1)

How would I do that?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM members
WHERE CURDATE() = DATE_ADD(renewal_date, INTERVAL $MONTH MONTH)
  OR (
    CURDATE() = DATE_ADD(reminder_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND blocker = 0
    );
```

This will get your original results and add the ones with reminder_date of one month ago and blocker = 0